# Is there a simple way to trace function calls in a complex call without mocking everything separately?

Tags: python, pytest

Assume that I don't care about occurring exceptions at all. I have a complex function that calls multiple functions along the way.. I want to test that with certain input parameters, certain functions will be called.

So basically, I am looking for something like:

```
@patch(
    "service.module.class.some_nested_function_1",
    new_callable=AsyncMock,
)
@patch(
    "service.module.class.some_nested_function_2",
    new_callable=AsyncMock,
)
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_complex_function(function2_mock, function1_mock):
    some_param = "abc"
    another_param = "xyz"
    try:
        call_complex_function("with_some_configuration")
    except:
        abort_crashing_function_and_continue_execution_in_complex_function()
    assert function2_mock.assert_called_once_with(some_param)
    assert function1_mock.assert_called_once_with(another_param)
```

**EDIT:** An alternative idea would be to have something like:

```
...
async def test_complex_function(function2_mock, function1_mock):
    ...
    mock_every_function_call_except_complex_function_to_return_zero()
    call_complex_function("with_some_configuration")
    assert function2_mock.assert_called_once_with(some_param)
    assert function1_mock.assert_called_once_with(another_param)
    ...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

### Function Call Counting Wrapper

Wrap your nested functions with this so that mocks aren't necessary and you can still see if certain functions were called or not called.

```
def count_calls_wrapper(fn):
    call_count = 0

    def _result(*args):
        nonlocal call_count
        call_count +=1
        return fn(*args)

    def _get_call_count():
        return call_count

    _result.get_call_count = _get_call_count

    return _result


def f1():
    return 10

f1 = count_calls_wrapper(f1)

assert(f1.get_call_count() == 0)

f1()

assert(f1.get_call_count() == 1)
```